# Building PTLIB using minGW

Tags: openssl, cygwin, openldap, mingw-w64, opalvoip

I'm currently facing several challenges while attempting to build PTLIB on MinGW. I've successfully resolved some dependencies, such as OpenSSL and Expat, but I'm encountering new issues during the build process.

Initially, PTLIB reported a missing SASL library, but I managed to install it. However, I'm now confronted with the following issue:

scss
Copy code
checking Open LDAP support... disabled due to disabled dependency HAS_DNS_RESOLVER
I'm seeking assistance from the community to help me overcome these challenges and successfully compile PTLIB on MinGW. I've already given up on Visual Studio due to difficulties.

If anyone has experience with building PTLIB on MinGW or can offer guidance on resolving the "HAS_DNS_RESOLVER" issue, your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to build ptlib for several years now, but I build all dependencies (and their dependencies, ...) myself too.

My build recipe for ptlib is here: https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/ptlib.winlib